Flutter Printing Package not getting Custom Page Size
I am using Flutter Printing Package to print pdf through my flutter app.
This is my code with custom page size.
await Printing.layoutPdf(
                  format: PdfPageFormat.standard.copyWith(
                    height: 2.3 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                    width: 4.7 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                    marginBottom: 0.05 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                    marginLeft: 0.05 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                    marginRight: 0.05 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                    marginTop: 0.05 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                  ),
                  onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) {
                    final pdf = pw.Document();
                    pdf.addPage(
                      pw.Page(
                        pageFormat: format,
                        // pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.standard.copyWith(
                        //   height: 2.3 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                        //   width: 4.7 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                        //   marginBottom: 0.05 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                        //   marginLeft: 0.05 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                        //   marginRight: 0.05 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                        //   marginTop: 0.05 * PdfPageFormat.cm,
                        // ),
                        orientation: pw.PageOrientation.landscape,
                        build: (pw.Context context) {
                          return pw.Align(
                            alignment: pw.Alignment.center,
                            child: pw.Container(
                                color: PdfColors.amber,
                                child:
                                    pw.Center(child: pw.Text("Hi I am Miraj"))),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                    return pdf.save();
                  });

This is my sticker pdf looks like when i view pdf

This is my sticker pdf looks like in print.layout

In the Second Picture you can see the marked area the page size is showing 4.6*3.80..
i am to be my paper size 2.3cm * 4.7cm

no I just colored the area to visualize the available area. The printer is Zebra ZT410. I didn't get any sdk documentation. How to use Zpl code in Zpl printer?? can you guide me ???

how to send my zpl cmd in my zebra printer through my flutter app???
